# Avoid repetition when using repositories and TPT

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using EF and TPT in a new project for my user-related tables, but I keep repeating myself and I don't see how I can fix the problem.
Basically, I have 4 tables: users (all), guests, admin and registered users. I then have a model for each table.

Since, I'm following the repository pattern, I've created:

- IUserRepository
- RegisteredUserRepository (implements the interface)
- GuestUsersRepository (implements the interface)
- AdminUsersRepository (implements the interface)

The thing is..***I just wanted a single UserRepository*** that implemented the interface because I have a lot of methods in my repositories that are basically the same. 
However, whenever I try to use a single repo, I keep getting problems, namely due to the fact that ***the different types of users have different properties*** (eg: registered and admin users have an email address, username and password whereas guest users don't). ***Therefore, I can't use generic methods*.**

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

IUserRepository:

```
 interface IUserRepository<T> where T: User  {

        T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        T GetById(int id);
        T GetByEmail(string email);
        T GetByUsername(string username);
        bool Login(string email, string password);
        bool Add(T user);
        void Update(T user);
        void Delete(T user);
```

RegisteredUserRepository:

```
 public class RegisteredUserRepository : IUserRepository<RegisteredUser> {
        // context here

        public RegisteredUser Find(Expression<Func<RegisteredUser, bool>> predicate) {
            return _db.Users.OfType<RegisteredUser>().SingleOrDefault(predicate);
        }

        public RegisteredUser GetById(int id) {
            return this.Find(u => u.Id == id);
        }

        // HERE lies my problem: I can't make all of these methods generic because there are some properties (eg: email) that registered and admin users have and that guests don't
        public RegisteredUser GetByEmail(string email) {
            return this.Find(u => u.Email == email); 
        }

        // same thing here...   
        public bool Login(string usernameOrEmail, string password) {
            var user = this.Find(u => u.Email == usernameOrEmail || a.Username == usernameOrEmail);
            return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(password, user.Password);
       }
```

GuestUserRepository:

```
  public class GuestUserRepository : IUserRepository<GuestUser> {
        // context here...

    public GuestUser Find(Expression<Func<GuestUser, bool>> predicate) {
         return db.Users.OfType<GuestUser>().SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    }

    public GuestUser GetById(int id) {
        return this.Find(g => g.Id == id);
    }

    // etc, etc
```

Comment: Why do you need a repository over entity framework? 

http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/

Comment: I'm just experimenting and trying different things because it's a great way to learn. However, I am reading the article you posted and it is indeed interesting what the author points out. 
I'd still like to know if there's a fix for the problem if

Comment: sorry, sent the comment before finishing and now I can't edit it - basically, I'd still like to know if there's a fix when using the repository pattern